# Youtube Music Snap does not open

Tags: permissions, snap

I have downloaded the stable version- 1.13.0 of youtube-music-desktop-app on Ubuntu 20.04.2

Nothing happens after clicking on the app icon. Trying to open it through terminal as superuser gives the following error:

mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied

Running the command without superuser or sudo gives no error, and it seemingly executes normally, but the app still does not open.

Comment: I'd suggest that you open `/etc/default/locale` for editing and remove the `LC_ALL` line. `LC_ALL` is not intended to be set in that file. Then reboot and let us know if it makes a difference.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I did what you asked and the locale errors are now gone. However, the "mkdir permission denied" still appears and the snap still doesn't start

Comment: Ok. I just installed `youtube-music-desktop-app` (from latest/stable channel) on my Ubuntu 20.10, and can't reproduce that error.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson OP mentioned they're trying to run it with superuser via terminal, i.e. `sudo` - which shouldn't be needed.

Comment: What happens when you run it in terminal *without* superuser privileges?  What errors does it give you?

Comment: Good catch @ThomasWard!

Comment: @ThomasWard it gives no error, but the app doesn't launch either. Nothing happens.

Comment: @dnaik: To increase the chance that somebody will help you with that last bit, I suggest that you edit your question again and let us know which Ubuntu version you are on and which channel you installed `youtube-music-desktop-app` from. Also please clarify the question, and drop the previously mentioned errors which are now gone.